# malloc 2D array leads to EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: c

While trying to initialize a board for the Game of Life, I get an error:

```
EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x200000000)
```

on line 9 (I've marked it in a comment). I'm using `malloc` to allocate memory to a 2D array, a board full of `struct cell`s. The method I found on StackOverflow. Am I doing something wrong? Also, there is a warning before I run the program that occurs on line 6:

```
Incompatible pointer types initializing 'struct cell *const' with an expression of type 'struct cell **'; dereference with *
```

Could this have something to do with it? Here's the code:

```
void init_board(int nrows, int ncols, struct cell ***board){

    //allocate memory for a 2D array
    *board = malloc(nrows * sizeof(*board) + nrows * ncols * sizeof(**board));

    //Now set the address of each row 
    struct cell * const firstrow = *board + nrows;
    for(int i = 0; i < nrows; i++)
    {
        *board[i] = firstrow + i * ncols; //EXC_BAD_ACCESS...
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < nrows; i++){ //fill the entire board with pieces
        for(int j = 0; j < ncols; j++){
            *board[j][i] = new_cell(i, j, 0);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, done. Doesn't solve this problem though.

Comment: what's wrong with a VLA?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[]` is higher order of [precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) than `*`

```
    // *board[i] = firstrow + i * ncols; //EXC_BAD_ACCESS...
    (*board)[i] = firstrow + i * ncols; //EXC_BAD_ACCESS...
```

Swap index order

```
        // *board[j][i] = new_cell(i, j, 0);
        (*board)[i][j] = new_cell(i, j, 0);
```

Comment: There are other concerns with the code: no allocation check, no error return, weak variable names, pointer type issue with `struct cell * const firstrow = *board + nrows;`, alignment issue had `struct cell` been a basic type, use of VLA, order of `nrows * ncols * sizeof(**board)`, yet the above should advance OP's code.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it did! I'm 2 weeks into learning C so I'm trying to simply get this to work before I start to think about writing good code.